# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser display none

Tags: php, domparser

i'm trying to figure out how to set elements invisible using the parser. here's what i tried which didn't work unfortunately:

```
$button->style = "display:none";
```

any ideas? thanks

Comment: just some <button> element ..

Comment: `<button>` is not a valid PHP type. What PHP type is `$button`?

Comment: it comes from the parser :) like this:
$button = $dom->find("button#save]",0);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use set setAttribute method  http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php

```
$button->setAttribute("style", "display:none");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which parser you're using, but if you want to hide some HTML element, you need to set the `style` attribute to `display:none`.

So access the `style` attribute of that `button` and set it / extend it with `display:none`.

According to the reference given at http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ (if that is the component you're using), this should do it:

```
$dom->find("button[id=save]",0)->style = 'display:none';
```

Answer (score -2):

Here my solution

```
$html->find('div[style=display:none]')
```